# javascript jquery sort ascociative numeric array ascending order and keep duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, duplicates, numeric

i have a numeric key => value array with missing keys. I want to keep the array as is, but sort it in a ascending order, and keep the duplicate key.

This is a keyboard keycodes array:

my codes is as follows:

```
var keyCodes = {
"192" : "~",
"49" : "!",
"50" : "@",
"51" : "#",
"52" : "$",
"53" : "%",
"54" : "^",
"55" : "&",
"56" : "*",
"57" : "(",
"48" : ")",
"173" : "_",
"61" : "+",
"219" : "{",
"221" : "}",
"220" : "|",
"59" : ":",
"222" : "\"",
"188" : "<",
"190" : ">",
"191" : "?",
"192" : "`",
"219" : "[",
"221" : "]",
"59" : ";",
"222" : "'",
"220" : "\\",
"188" : ",",
"190" : ".",
"191" : "/",
"49" : "1",
"50" : "2",
"51" : "33",
"51" : "34",
"51" : "35",
"51" : "3",
"52" : "4",
"53" : "5",
"54" : "6",
"55" : "7",
"39" : "ArrowRight"
};
```

this is a portion of the array: here there are 4 x 51 key value pairs. i would like that when the array is sorted i get ....."49" : "1", "51" : "3", "51" : "33", "51" : "34", "51" : "35", ......

i have tried almost everything, the last thing i tried was the following:

```
function checkKeys(arr, key){
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
if(arr[i] == key)
return 1;
}
return 0;
}   


    $inArr = [];
    $inArrd = [];
    $newCodes = {};
Object.keys(keyCodes).forEach(function (key) {
var keysC = checkKeys($inArr, key);
if(keysC === 1){
/*tried creating an array of duplicates and then later remove or change them in the main array manually*/
$inArrd.push(key);
return;
}

$inArr.push(key);
$newCodes[key] = keyCodes[key];
return;
});

console.log($inArrd);
```

did not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

i solved it:
the object keys takes unique indexes only, meaning if you have 4 indexes each named "51" Object.keys returns only one key called "51". for this reason I couldnt achieve my desired result.

/*dont use unless you want uniqu keys */

```
Object.keys(keyCodes).forEach(function (key) {

})
```

I switched to jQuery and used this method instead:

```
$.each( keyCodes, function( key, value ) { 
/* do what ever */
})
```